# Помогите составить команду cron

Tags: cron

Всем привет, помогите составить задание крон которое будет запускать скрипт:
каждый день в `00:00`, `00:30`, `01:30`, `02:00`.

Answer (score 5):

- 00 0 * * * root run-parts `<path_to_script>`
- 30 0 * * * root run-parts `<path_to_script>`
- 30 1 * * * root run-parts `<path_to_script>`
- 00 2 * * * root run-parts `<path_to_script>`

**UPD**

Для того чтоб запускать каждый день в определенные часы можно записать так:

- 00 0-2 * * * root run-parts `<path_to_script>`

запустит скрипт каждые сутки в 00:00, 1:00 и в 2:00

Можно также задать не интервалом, а перечислением:

- 00 0,2,23 * * * root run-parts `<path_to_script>`

скрипт запустится каждые сутки в 00:00, 2:00 и в 23:00

Comment: А можно сделать это оной командой, как к примеру: 0 12,13,14 * * * - запускать команду каждый час с 12 до 14

Comment: @YriyIvan.
обновил ответ

Comment: Да, верно, будет запускаться в 00:00, 1:00 и 2:00,но именно в 0 минут, а задача стоит запускать и 0 минут и в 30...

Comment: так Вам же не надо вроде в 1:00 запускать?

Comment: По сути меня интересует можно ли сделать и следующих двух команд одну:
0 0-23 * * * и 
30 14-23 * * *

Comment: 1-команда будет запускать каждый час с 00:00 до 23:00; 2-команда - запускает в с 14:30 до 23:30, каждый час

Comment: @YriyIvan.
К сожалению не удастся сделать одну команду из этих двух