# Node.js cron как задать время оповещения на кроне?

Tags: node.js, cron

Вопрос по поводу крона, есть функция

```
Cron.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', function(){
  console.log('Do something....');
});
```

Какой шаблон нужно указать здесь чтобы каждый день в 10 утра скрипт выполнял эту операцию?

Comment: и ещё дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461952/178576

Comment: [`$ man 5 crontab`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=crontab&category=5&russian=0): указать `10` вместо `*` для часов и `0` вместо `*` для минут. // ещё ближе информация — прямо в описании метки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info

Answer (score 1):

```
Cron.scheduleJob('0 0 10 * * *', function(){
  console.log('Do something....');
});
```

А вообще читайте внимательнее [документацию](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron#available-cron-patterns)